# How i can install .alx file for different version in Blackberry device?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

> Hello, i had develop application in blackberry version 5.0. Now i want to
>   install .alx file in device using Desktop Manager. it is install fine
>   when i install .alx in device which have version 5.0 but when i
>   install that in 9700Bold device which has 6.0 OS and it will give following error.
>
> Does any Body have idea how support multiple os in Blackberry? please
>   tell me. 
>   Thanx in advance.

[image]

Comment: what is the error ..... can you tell us.

Comment: i got solution,  you can see my ans which i had post.

Comment: Right now i can't accept, it allow me after 2 days..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution for my question and it works fine in all devices. We need to create new `fileset` tag in our `.alx` file and we have to make new directories for each version.

Suppose : You had developed app in 5.0 and want to install `.alx` file in 6.0 also.

```
Step 1: Make folder, suppose ABC in which paste `.alx` file (After signing the app).
Step 2: Make 2 folders 1. 5.0.0  2. 6.0.0  in ABC folder.
Step 3: open .alx file and change as following:



 <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[5.0.0)">
            <directory >5.0.0</directory>
            <files >Appname.cod</files>
        </fileset>


        <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[6.0.0)">
            <directory >6.0.0</directory>
            <files >Appname.cod</files>
</fileset>

Step 4: Now connect mobile with PC using desktop software.
Step 5: Go to application tab of desktop software -> import app in device.
```

Now it will work fine. For more knowledge visit below link

> http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Create-a-single-alx-file-to-install-multiple-versions-of-an/ta-p/445156